# CakePHP delete cookie doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I'm trying to delete the cookie set by Facebook Graph API using $this->Cookie->delete() but it's not working at all. The cookie is on my localhost domain and not a secure one. I'm using Cak Please help.

Answer (score 4):

The Facebook cookie is owned by Facebook, so you can't delete it. To remove it, the user needs to logout of FB itself.

Answer (score 0):

It difficult to resolve your issue with the information provided, but it's mostly likely that you're not passing the incorrect parameter to the delete function.

As a start, I'd suggest looking into the framework itself to see if CookieComponent->setCookie() is being called with the correct parameters:  [http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/cookie-component/#line-38](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/cookie-component/#line-380)